# Can I install 3/8" engineered Hickory hardwood over a painted OSB subfloor?

Tags: installation, hardwood, engineered-flooring

We bought a large badly abused foreclosed home to restore. The home exists in an area where hardwoods throughout are the norm for resale and engineered wood in the same where good product is used and respected by knowledgeable buyers.

When we first bought the property we knew we would later hardwood the entire home once the renovations were completed but in order to afford our project we had to live in the home while renovating.

Since the entire home had horribly pet stained carpets and damaged floor coverings the first thing we did was remove ALL the older carpeting and vinyl goods and then we sealed all the OSB with KILLS oil based primmer and then sealed the floors with Bear brand latex Porch paint (2 coats).

This offered us amazingly easy to clean and oder free floors that allowed us to comfortably live and clean the home over the past 2 years while waiting to install our hardwood last when all our updates were completed.

The home is now done and we are ready to install our hardwoods. BUT one question has arose in our minds.....is it SAFE to now install a 3/8" engineered hardwood product over all the OSB painted floors?? Can covering the now painted OSB cause any vapor issues or problems with the hardwood once installed.

We planned to use ether 15pound Rosin or Roofing felt as well in between the new wood and the OSB subfloor. Any comments on if we did a bad thing by painting the floors as we did? We did not account for this being an issue or creating a major cost to fix but want to make sure it will be safe and not cause any problems later on in the home and future longevity of the hardwood product (Armstrong American Handscrape).

Comment: Have you tried contacting Armstrong? They should be able to tell you if the subfloor will pose a problem with their product.